# how to search the dataset for specific data

Tags: c#, asp.net, dataset

I just wanted to ask how to search dataset for specific data because I want to search summary for specific  keywords  and bind it to repeater I have where expression and it is not working

```
        string keyword = "where summary like %"+ txtbKeyword.Text +"%" ;


        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        int selectedTopicID = Convert.ToInt32(ddlTopics.SelectedValue);
        int selectedSkillID = Convert.ToInt32(ddlSkills.SelectedValue);
        int selectedTypeID = Convert.ToInt32(ddlTypes.SelectedValue);
        ds = Resoursce.Search_Resource(selectedTopicID, selectedSkillID, selectedTypeID);
        lbl_totalResult.Text = ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count.ToString();
        rp_resList.DataSource = ds.Tables[0].Select(keyword);
        rp_resList.DataBind();
```

System.Data.SyntaxErrorException was unhandled by user code

```
 HResult=-2146232032
  Message=Syntax error: Missing operand after 'summary' operator.
  Source=System.Data
  StackTrace:
       at System.Data.ExpressionParser.Parse()
       at System.Data.DataExpression..ctor(DataTable table, String expression, Type type)
       at System.Data.DataTable.Select(String filterExpression)
       at Christoc.Modules.ResourcesFilter.View.ddlTopics_SelectedIndexChanged(Object sender, EventArgs e) in c:\inetpub\wwwroot\ideaPark\DesktopModules\ResourcesFilter\View.ascx.cs:line 120
       at System.Web.UI.WebControls.ListControl.OnSelectedIndexChanged(EventArgs e)
       at System.Web.UI.Page.RaiseChangedEvents()
       at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
  InnerException:
```

Comment: Please, explain what do you mean for 'search'. You need a subset of data extracted from the tables inside the dataset? If yes, what is your condition (ie.WHERE?)

Comment: what I am looking for is to find record where like

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use the DataTable.Select() method.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t5ce3dyt.aspx

Microsoft's example:

```
  // Presuming the DataTable has a column named Date. 
  string expression = "Date = '1/31/1979' or OrderID = 2";
  // string expression = "OrderQuantity = 2 and OrderID = 2";

  // Sort descending by column named CompanyName. 
  string sortOrder = "CompanyName ASC";
  DataRow[] foundRows;

  // Use the Select method to find all rows matching the filter.
  foundRows = table.Select(expression, sortOrder);
```