# How can I check data between an sql database and a combobox?

Tags: c#, sql-server, wpf, time, dataset

I want to add a new row:

```
SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter("select time from foglalas", c1);
SqlCommandBuilder scb = new SqlCommandBuilder(da);
da.MissingSchemaAction = MissingSchemaAction.AddWithKey;
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
da.Fill(ds, "fog");
DataRow uj = ds.Tables["fog"].NewRow();
```

combobox value 12:00 <<-- time type.

I have a combobox, and I want to make sure that a row is not added yet using the `combobox data==slq` query result

How can I do that?

Comment: It's not very clear what you're asking.
Do you want to find if there is '12:00' within your `ds`? If so - it was already asked - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16366297/how-to-search-the-dataset-for-specific-data. If that is not the case - consider putting your question in other words.

Comment: i have a combobox which contains time format(1:00,2:00 ....etc), and in database , i am saving time format(1:00,2:00....23:00)and i don't want to add the same time because of redundacy, how can i check that the 2 data(between database and combobox).
sorry for my bad english.

Comment: So check your DataSet before inserting with the help of `Select` like is in my previous link. Does that work? Also what is the data type of column `time` in `foglalas`?

Comment: time in foglalas is nvarchar.Its hard to compare 2 text , and I dont understand how can i do that, what you linked, i think is not good for my probleme

Comment: I've tried explaining how to use `Select` as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your comments to the question I think `Select` may help you. I have prototyped some code here:

```
var valueFromCombobox = "12:00";
var fog = ds.Tables["fog"];
DataRow[] foundRows = fog.Select("time = '" + valueFromCombobox + "'");
if (foundRows.Length > 0)
    Console.WriteLine("Already there!");
else
    Console.WriteLine("Not there yet - add it.");
```