# Changing the Rows state in DataTable if it meets the following condition

Tags: c#

i have two tables: `DataTable dt_o;` and `DataTable dt_m;`

Contents of `dt_m`:

```
ID        |    Name      |    Age    
--------------------------------------
08        |    Farel     |     18      
07        |    Ema       |     18
10        |    Sophie    |     19
11        |    Cyril     |     12
```

Contents of `dt_o`:

```
ID        |    Name      |    Age    
--------------------------------------
08        |    Farel     |     19      
07        |    Ema       |     18
10        |    Sophie    |     19
```

the row from `dt_m` with the `ID` of `08` should be set to `row.SetModified()` since once of it's columns value where different in the other Table[`dt_o`]

and the row from `dt_m` with the `ID` of `11` should be set to `row.SetAdded()` since it doesn't exist in the other table...

and the rest of the row, there row states would be set to `unchange state`..

any code suggestion?

Answer (score 1):

I would search the tables for the specified requirements you're seeking using the answer of this post: [how to search the dataset for specific data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16366297/how-to-search-the-dataset-for-specific-data)

Then just set the state of the rows returned based on what you wanna do. For example:

```
dataSet.AcceptChanges(); //If you'd like to start with everything as "unchanged"

foreach(DataRow row in rowsReturnedFromQuery1)
    row.SetAdded();

foreach(DataRow row2 in rowsReturnedFromQuery2)
    row2.SetModified();
```

Hope this helps. I'm sure you can do this using Linq as well.